# Is there any estimate for powers of binomial?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis, inequality

It is well known that
$$(a+b)^2 \leq 2 a^2 + 2b^2$$
and that this formula holds for power $n$ natural numbers, i.e.
$$(a+b)^n \leq c_n a^n + c_nb^n$$
where $c_n>0$ is a constant

Given $\alpha >0$ is it there some formula of this kind?
$$(a+b)^\alpha \leq c_\alpha a^\alpha + c_\alpha b^\alpha$$
where $c_\alpha>0$ is a constant

Comment: What is $c_n$ in$(a+b)^n \leq c_n a^n + c_nb^n
$

Comment: $\sqrt{a+b}\geq \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{a}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{b}$ in general, so unless I'm misunderstanding the meaning of $c_{n}$ and $c_{\alpha}$, no, there is no such formula.

Comment: not even for $\alpha >1?$

Comment: $a,b>0, \alpha>1\Rightarrow (a+b)^\alpha\leq 2^{\alpha-1}(a^\alpha+b^\alpha)$

Comment: $\alpha < 1$ can't work as pointed out by @LieutenantZipp

Comment: proof of it @IvanKaznacheyeu or referenceses?

Comment: Try Young's inequality for $a^{n-k} b^k$

Comment: For proof one can consider $f(u)=\frac{(a+b)^\alpha}{a^\alpha+b^\alpha}=\frac{(1+u)^\alpha}{1+u^\alpha}$, $u=b/a > 0$. This function has maximum at $u=1$ if $\alpha > 1$. Therefore $f(u)\leq f(1)=2^{\alpha-1}$.

Comment: The function has minimum at $u=1$ if $0<\alpha<1$, that's why inequality reverses for $\sqrt{a}$ and $\sqrt{b}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(a+b)^n\le 2^{n-1}a^n+2^{n-1}b^n$ by Power-Mean inequality. However, $\frac{(a+b)^n}{a^n+b^n}$ does not have a maximum as $n$ varies.